# GFCI sometimes trips when light switched, or just randomly

Tags: electrical, wiring, bathroom, gfci

Every now and then, a bathroom GFCI (nothing plugged in) randomly trips, and also sometimes (<5% of the time) when I turn on the light switch in that bathroom. The bathroom has a GFCI in one box, and two switches (in one box) for light and exhaust fan (not above shower). I assume the light and exhaust fan are not downstream from the GFCI since they remain on when the GFCI has tripped. I also assume all components are around 17 years old.

That GFCI seems to have a downstream connection to another GFCI in another bathroom. I assume that second GFCI just needs to be a regular receptacle, but that is another question :). A GFCI tester indicates correct wiring for both GFCIs.

Comment: If the GFCI is in fact 17 years old, then the first step is to replace it.   It may be the GFCI is going bad.

Comment: @Tyson I actually had purchased a new GFCI but didn't install it yet because I was worried I would just be hiding a problem. If you think there is nothing to worry about, then I will just replace the GFCI.

Comment: Replace it.  The GFCI is either the problem, or replacing it will have no change, or it will make it worse.  It won't mask a problem.

Comment: Is anything connected to the LOAD terminals of the GFCI?

Comment: @Harper the GFCI that trips has it's LOAD terminals connected to what I believe is the GFCI in another bathroom. I am assuming this because when I press the test button on the GFCI in that other bathroom, that GFCI does not trip but this GFCI does trip.

Comment: @jordan try moving the wires on the LOAD side of this GFCI to the LINE side.  You would need to put pigtails on the LINE wires of the GFCI and then wirenut them to supply power and also the former LOAD wires.   Nothing will be on LOAD when you're done.

Comment: I never give the advice to move the load to the line side of a GFCI without instructions to analyze and understand the circuit completely.  The problem is that someone created it originally, someone that didn't understand the circuit  modified it (by adding a GFCI), and now @harper wants to make an assumption that based on what we can see from here (not much) that there is no OTHER reason for the remainder of the circuit to be protected from the first GFCI.

Comment: @Tyson A GFCI feeding a GFCI is pretty much the picture postcard definition of *no earthly idea how to use the LOAD terminals*, most of the time these things are installed haphazardly to satisfy a realtor's checklist to sell the house, and the LOAD side is simply used as two more screws.

Comment: @harper what about the possibility of a third outlet that's not a GFCI that's protected by the load terminals of GFCI #1?  While I agree that GFCI#2 probably happened as a result of a real estate transaction we can't assume that there are NO OTHER locations that are being protected from the load terminals of GFCI #1.

Comment: Additionally daisy chained gfci's don't create nuisance trips.

Comment: @Harper would having a GFCI on the LOAD side of a GFCI cause the upstream GFCI to randomly trip, and would moving it as you described actually solve the problem? I agree that the downstream GFCI#2 was probably installed to replace a regular receptacle that someone didn't know was already protected.

Comment: @Tyson I tried to check almost every other outlet inside the house after GFCI#1 was tripped, and according to a GFCI tester only GFCI#2 was impacted. I checked the third/final GFCI in another bathroom and that was not impacted. Is it allowable (in Canada) for the bathroom lights/exhaust fan circuit to feed GFCI#1 which feeds GFCI#2? I vaguely remember reading something about if you have a GFCI protecting a receptacle in another room, then that circuit can only contain other receptacles and not lights/etc.

Comment: Daisy chained GFCI's don't create a nuisance tripping condition.  They are a nusiance however to reset.  Day for example an appliance plugged into #2 causes a real ground fault, 1 and 2 will both trip, but they must be reset in the order 1 then 2 because 2 won't reset unless it has power feeding it.  As long as your certain no other outlets in required locations (kitchen, baths, garages, basements, outdoor etc) are part of this circuit then separate these so that they will operate independently.  It's not something that should just be suggested on a whim without more comment however.

Comment: @Tyson I double checked a (non-GFCI) outlet in the kitchen ~4ft from the sink and that doesn't seem to protected by either of the GFCIs in the bathrooms. I assume the kitchen ones were installed by the home builder since there hasn't been a kitchen renovation. I was hoping to see that outlet no longer work when I trip the GFCI#1 in the bathroom, but it didn't. I wonder if that should have GFCI protection. I haven't yet checked outside outlets to see if they are protected by GFCI#1. I will start by just replacing GFCI#1 (and keeping it daisy chained with GFCI#2 for now) to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Tyson, yes they do, and you're on a "high horse" here, and you're wrong. **An outlet doesn't count as protected unless it's *labeled* "GFCI protected"**, so you are handwringing over *accidental* protection the installer provided due to incompetence. There is no code requirement to continue that.  And yes, OP *must* divide to conquer.  He cannot troubleshoot it otherwise

Comment: Question is about 17 year old GFCI in Canada. I don’t know Canadian code 17 years ago re:“GFCI protected” labels.  Although NEC required in USA then, they weren’t applied frequently, at least where I live.  If they did get stuck on, over 17 years they may have been removed.  Specifically, @Harper your sore because I called you out for giving poor advice above, yet now you admit the homeowner should troubleshoot and “must divide to conquer” as you put it.  Honestly, right back at ya, with your high horse comment..  there is no one on this entire SE on a higher horse than you are...daily.

Comment: @Tyson Drama queen much?  You are the only person who thinks that's poor advice, *and even there* you had to "read between the lines" to infer  something to complain about.  **This malicious inference** is insufferably rude, and is the only thing really happening here.  Get over yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the circuit more carefully. Slapping in a tester doesn't really tell you if it's wired correctly.  Noting what goes out when it trips is an incomplete mapping effort.

A GFCI+receptacle combo can be tripped by any of the following:

- A device plugged into one of its sockets, which has a ground fault.  Presumably either this device has a 3-prong cord, or energy is leaking to something grounded (e.g. the apocryphal dropping the hair dryer in a sink of water).
- Something wired into the LOAD terminals has a ground fault, and the GFCI is correctly detecting it.
- The GFCI device itself is malfunctioning.

Nothing is plugged in, so we can check that off the list.  You have no idea what is attached to the LOAD terminals, so that's a big fuzzy question mark.  Then of course the GFCI device itself could be failing.

Now you say you think the LOAD terminals feed another GFCI device. Ohhhhh...kay.  You can do that, but you're basically playing a "Yo dawg" joke on yourself.  The protection is entirely redundant.  The downline GFCI adds no additional protection.  Further, if there is a ground fault downline of both GFCIs, **both of them will trip**.  Some GFCIs can be "peculiar" about the sequence they are reset in.  This can drive you nuts.  I would eliminate that arrangement if it's feasible to do so.

All receptacles protected by an upstream GFCI should have a "GFCI Protected" sticker or label.

Some people have a big problem with the idea of simply removing a load from the LOAD terminals without knowing exactly what it is.  I somewhat agree, but I would say that if you didn't know it was protected (and there was no label), where's the loss?  If you really want to, you can get a GFCI tester and do an exhaustive search of every outlet that loses power when that breaker is turned off, and see whether it loses GFCI protection if you remove it from the LOAD terminals.